# Defining many relations in typeorm for private entity properties

Tags: typescript, many-to-many, typeorm, one-to-many, object-relational-model

I'm using typeorm library for entity mapping in my node app. I want to include many type relations between entities. I have followed the docs and in it the entity properties are marked as public, so we can access it from other entities. I have defined entity properties as private. So I have created a `getProperty` method in entity to give back the property on entity instance. Now typeorm throws an error saying `entity.getProperty is not a function`.

**User Entity**

```
@Entity()
class User {

    private USER_ID_PREFIX: string = "uid-";

    @PrimaryColumn()
    private id: string;
    @Column({nullable: false, length: 15})
    private firstname: string;
    @Column({nullable: false, length: 15})
    private lastname: string;
    @Column({nullable: false, unique: true, length: 25})
    private email: string;
    @Column({nullable: false})
    private password: string;
    @OneToMany(() => Role, (role) => role.getProperty(EntityProperty.USER))
    private roles: Role[];

    public constructor(...args: any[]) {
        if (args.length === 0)
            return;
        if (args.length === 1) {
            if (args[0] instanceof UserCreateRequestDto) {
                let requestDto = args[0];
                this.id = this.USER_ID_PREFIX + randomUUID();
                this.firstname = requestDto.getProperty(DtoProperty.FIRSTNAME);
                this.lastname = requestDto.getProperty(DtoProperty.LASTNAME);
                this.email = requestDto.getProperty(DtoProperty.EMAIL);
                this.password = requestDto.getProperty(DtoProperty.PASSWORD);
            }
        }
    }

    public getProperty(property: EntityProperty): any {
        if (property === EntityProperty.ID)
            return this.id;
        if (property === EntityProperty.FIRSTNAME)
            return this.firstname;
        if (property === EntityProperty.LASTNAME)
            return this.lastname;
        if (property === EntityProperty.EMAIL)
            return this.email;
        if (property === EntityProperty.PASSWORD)
            return this.password;
        if (property === EntityProperty.ROLES)
            return this.roles;
        throw new Error(`No such entity property as ${property.toString()} exists in User`);
    }
}

export default User;
```

**Role Entity**

```
@Entity()
class Role {

    private ROLE_ID_PREFIX: string = "rid-";

    @PrimaryColumn()
    private id: string;
    @Column({nullable: false})
    private role: string;
    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.getProperty(EntityProperty.ROLES))
    private user: User;

    public constructor(...args: any[]) {
        if (args.length === 0)
            return;
        if (args.length === 1) {
            if (args[0] instanceof RoleCreateRequestDto) {
                let requestDto = args[0];
                this.id = this.ROLE_ID_PREFIX + randomUUID();
                this.role = requestDto.getProperty(DtoProperty.ROLE);
            }
        }
    }

    public getProperty(property: EntityProperty): any {
        if (property === EntityProperty.ID)
            return this.id;
        if (property === EntityProperty.ROLE)
            return this.role;
        if (property === EntityProperty.USER)
            return this.user;
        throw new Error(`No such entity property as ${property.toString()} exists in Role`);
    }
}

export default Role;
```

**Error stack**

```
query: SELECT VERSION() AS `version`
Error initializing mysql datasource TypeError: user.getProperty is not a function
    at RelationMetadata.givenInverseSidePropertyFactory (D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-auth-nodejs\src\entities\Role.ts:22:43)
    at RelationMetadata.buildInverseSidePropertyPath (D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-auth-nodejs\node_modules\src\metadata\RelationMetadata.ts:628:29)
    at D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-auth-nodejs\node_modules\src\metadata-builder\EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1116:26
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EntityMetadataBuilder.computeInverseProperties (D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-auth-nodejs\node_modules\src\metadata-builder\EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:1096:34)
    at D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-auth-nodejs\node_modules\src\metadata-builder\EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:158:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at EntityMetadataBuilder.build (D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-auth-nodejs\node_modules\src\metadata-builder\EntityMetadataBuilder.ts:157:25)
    at ConnectionMetadataBuilder.buildEntityMetadatas (D:\Swivel_Projects\Ignite\Project 1\backend\ignite-auth-nodejs\node_modules\src\connection\ConnectionMetadataBuilder.ts:106:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `TypeORM` requires the properties to be `public` because TypeORM relies on direct access to the properties  but in you code you have marked entity properties to `private`. So this can be solved by modifying your code as  :

```
@Entity()
class User {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    public id: string;

    @Column({ nullable: false, length: 15 })
    public firstname: string;

    @Column({ nullable: false, length: 15 })
    public lastname: string;

    @Column({ nullable: false, unique: true, length: 25 })
    public email: string;

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    public password: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Role, (role) => role.user)
    public roles: Role[];

    // Rest of the code...
}

@Entity()
class Role {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    public id: string;

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    public role: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.roles)
    public user: User;

    // Remaining code...
}
```